# Unity C# unknown reason for error code

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

Sorry to be a pain, but I really can't for the life of me figure out whats wrong with my code. I am building a simple space shooting game in Unity, using C#.

The have written a script to tie to two planes, that will cause them to scroll as a background.

However, for some reason that I really cant figure out, I am getting the error code:

> Assets/SCripts/parallaxScrolling.cs(26,46): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

Here's the code, thanks:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class parallaxScrolling : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    public float speed; //declare a variable for the movement speed overall


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        float move = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate (Vector3.down * move, Space.World); //this moves the object down at speed variable

        float heightLimit = -9;
        float yLimit = 11;

        if (transform.position.y <= heightLimit) 
        {
            transform.position = Vector2(transform.position.x,yLimit,transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, the last line is Vector3, not Vector2, that was just me trying something out....still not fixed.

Comment: So which is line 26?

Comment: where Vector3 is declared? Can i see it?

Comment: Line 26: "  transform.position = Vector3(transform.position.x,yLimit,transform.position.z);"

Comment: What is `Vector2`, `Vector2(transform.position.x,yLimit,transform.position.z);` does not look valid unless it is a method within your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using C#, so you have to declare objects with the `new` keyword, as your Vector3. That is, just add `new` in front of `Vector3` (the one indicated as Vector2 in your code, in line 26).

Answer (score -1):

transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,yLimit,transform.position.z);